# Firebase Stripe Setup Issues

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to deploy a new function called 'createStripeCheckout', but I keep getting an error stating that eslint command wasn't found:

davidknight@Davids-MacBook-Air HTML % firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'studiopick-f6c1f'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

sh: eslint: command not found

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code127

Answer (score 0):

Have you have added [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) dependency in your package.json file?